# Acrobat Javascript dialog doesn't return all field values

Tags: javascript, acrobat

This is my first attempt at kludge a somewhat intelligent document in Acrobat JavaScript. I'm not using Acrobat, but a free app called PDFill which allows entering JavaScript, but can't run it. I'm running my scripts by opening them in Acrobat Reader which doesn't have a JavaScript console (but please let me know if I just haven't found it).

**The goal** is to create a form which pops up as the user opens the document, asks for his name, company and email address, then sends it to the server via a HTTP call.

**The problem** is that the form doesn't seem to return all the fields in the `commit()` method. Only the `name` field works properly.

This is how the form looks like when it appears. The `name` field is filled, but the rest aren't. The order of fields doesn't matter, it's always the same.

[image: No field content...]

This is what the dialog in `commit()` displays. Apparently the `email` field's value is still received, but the field's name is lost.

[image: Only part of the data...]

**Source:**

```
var dataDialog = {
    initialize: function (dialog) {
        dialog.load({
            company: 'Whatever Co. Ltd.',
            name: 'John Doe',
            email: 'johndoe@whatever.com'
        });
    },

    commit: function (dialog) {
        var data = dialog.store();

        app.alert(JSON.stringify(data));

        //  Form validation
        if (data.name.length < 3) {
            app.alert('Please enter your name!');
            app.execDialog(dataDialog);
        }

        if (data.company.length < 2) {
            app.alert('Please enter the company name!');
            app.execDialog(dataDialog);
        }

        //  Send to URL
        // this.getURL('http://localhost:5000/pdfReceive/' + encodeURIComponent(data.name) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(data.company) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(data.email));
    },

    description: {
        name: "DataDialog",
        elements: [
            {
                type: "view",
                elements: [
                    { name: "Fill this form, mortal!", type: "static_text", },
                    { type: "gap" }
                ]
            },
            {
                type: "view",
                elements: [
                    { name: "Who owns you:", type: "static_text" },
                    { item_id: "company", type: "edit_text", char_width: 50 }
                ]
            },

            {
                type: "view",
                elements: [
                    { name: "How they call you:", type: "static_text" },
                    { item_id: "name", type: "edit_text", char_width: 50 }
                ]
            },

            {
                type: "view",
                elements: [
                    { name: "Your email:", type: "static_text" },
                    { item_id: "email", type: "edit_text", char_width: 50 },
                    { type: "ok", }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
};

app.execDialog(dataDialog);
```

**Update:** Interestingly, if I rename the form fields from `email`, `company`, etc. to `txt1`, `txt2`, etc. they work. While it's an acceptable solution for this simple task, can someone confirm that there are restrictions on field names?

Comment: You maybe should avoid trailing commas after the last element in objects. Modern JS engines don't care about them, but I remember that Acrobats JS engine was far less tolerant in some cases (some years ago, at least).

Comment: Thanks, fixed it, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, and it's ridiculous. None of the form field names can be longer than 4 characters. Over 4 characters the field name will become a dot character, like on the screenshot. If two fields have names longer than 4 characters, one will disappear.

Can't tell if it's a bug, a feature or it's just Friday.

Comment: Consider it a Friday Afternoon Feature…